# Является ли десятичная запись числа симметричной

Tags: алгоритм, pascal

Дано четырехзначное число. Определите, является ли его десятичная запись симметричной. Если число симметричное, то выведите 1, иначе выведите любое другое целое число. Число может иметь меньше четырех знаков, тогда нужно считать, что его десятичная запись дополняется слева незначащими нулями.

***При решении этой задачи нельзя пользоваться условной инструкцией if и циклами***

Пример: ввод: 2002, вывод = 1;

Пример: ввод 2008, вывод = 37;

Опять же накидал неверное решение :(
намекните как это все делается **без циклов и условий!**

```
//Симметричное число
var a, b: longint;
begin
readln(a);
b:= a;
a:= a div 1000;
b:= b mod 1000;
case a of
  11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99: writeln(' ',a + 1);
  end;
writeln(' ',a);
writeln(' ',b);
end.
```

Answer (score 9):

```
read(n);
//получаем 3 и 4 цифры
k := n mod 100;
//в n теперь 1 и 2 цифры
n := n div 100;
//в K меняем цифры местами
k := k div 10 + k mod 10 * 10;
//если число симметрично (левая и перевернутая правая части равны ) то получается 1, иначе "другое число"
write( n - k + 1 );
```

Comment: Только в начале надо обезапасить себя ** n := n mod 10000;**

Answer (score 2):

так всё в принципе просто
а1,а2,а3,а4  - соответственно 1, 2, 3, 4 цифра в числе (думаю проблем с их получением нет) 
все они интовские

writeln((a1 * 10+a2)-(a4 * 10+a3)+1);

в итоге если они равны то разность даст ноль, а прибавление единицы нужную единицу.
если они  не равны, единица вроде никогда не получится=)

Comment: осталось всего-лишь получить эти цифры)

Comment: Задано число n;


n = n %10000; a4 = n % 10; a3 = (n/10)%10; a2 = (n/100)%10; a1 = n/1000;

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант решение такое (`x` - число):

```
a = x / 1000

b = (x - a*1000)/ 100

c = (x - a*1000 - b*100) / 10

d = x mod 10

### min, max без if
max1 = a mod d + d mod a

min1 = a + d - max1

max2 = b mod c + c mod d

min2 = b + c - max2

result = (min2 + 1) / (max2 + 1) * (min1 + 1) / (max1 + 1)
```

В таком случае, если равны, должно выдавать 1, иначе 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a : longint;
    b : string;

readln(a);
s := Format('%04d', [a]);
a := Integer(Copy(s, 1, 2) = Copy(s, 3, 2));
writeln(' ',a);
```

думаю как то так. Будет выводится 1 либо 0

Comment: Нет, не так, вы косвенно используете условие. Задачу необходимо решить только арифметическими операциями.

Comment: Может и так но в условии про "только арифметическими операциями" ничего не сказано.

>> При решении этой задачи нельзя пользоваться условной инструкцией if и циклами

ни слова про арифметику :)

Comment: Да да, можно придраться, но здравый смысл говорит, что это читерство :)

Answer (score 0):

Извините, что на С++. Но код короткий и перевести его в Паскаль ничего не стоит.
Если без циклов и if, тогда так:

```
int n = 9889;
bool fun(int n)
{
   AnsiString s = IntToStr(n), s1, s2;
   s1 = s[1] + s[2];
   s2 = s[4] + s[3];
   return s1 == s2;
}
```

или

```
int fun(int n)
{
   AnsiString s = IntToStr(n), s1, s2;
   s1 = s[1] + s[2];
   s2 = s[4] + s[3];
   return(1 - StrToInt(s2) + StrToInt(s1)); 
}
```

Comment: При решении этой задачи нельзя пользоваться условной инструкцией if и циклами

Comment: Пардон, пардон, не заметил.

Answer (score -1):

PYTHON:

```
number = str(input())

first_number_part = number[:2]
second_number_part = number[2:][::-1]

print(int(first_number_part == second_number_part))
```

Comment: Извините,  а причём здесь python?

Comment: Какая разница какой язык? Суть алгоритма вычисления от этого не изменяется

Comment: Большая разница, в Pascal нет срезов как в Python